# Private variables in the controller scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In angular, following the demos, I can define a controller as:

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.todos = [
                    {text:'learn angular', done:true},
                    {text:'build an angular app', done:false},
                    {text:'empty dishwasher', done:false}];

    $scope.oldtodos = [];
    var oldtodos2 = [];
    ...
```

You'll note that I have two `oldtodos`.  One on the $scope and one that is just a local var.  I think the latter approach is the way to go if you want to encapsulate this variable - i.e. no-one other than the controller has any interest in it and the former is good if you want to pass the variable back to the model

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want to keep a private copy of oldTodos around in the event you have to either refer back to them or resurrect one of them or something. In that case, it probably makes sense not to put the oldTodos into the scope. As Maxim said, scope is relevant if you want to bind values to the view. If you just want to save the oldTodos so keep a reference to them, a normal variable is fine.

Then, if you want to bring one of them back, just copy it into the $scope.todos and back it comes.

Note that you can also abstract all of the todos into a service and inject the service into your controller for another level of encapsulation and better testing strategy. It will also enable you to share the todos across controllers if that's necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, if you want AngularJS app to interact with the application scope, then you need to add the data in the scope. That's it.

`$scope.oldtodos` is the correct way to add data to the scope and it can be referred by name `oldtodos` in HTML template. While `var oldtodos2` is private in your controller, so angular will not be able to access this data in the template since it is not in the scope.